# Is there any way to check the backup that android does?

Tags: backup, google-account, google-backup

Today I have been researching a bit about the Android backup options (since I have seen some people having to lose all their data due to ICS serious bugs).

From now, I prefer to use native options, such as the "default" option or the `adb backup -all` command.

**But my question is about the regular way**.

I enabled the `Settings->Backup->Backup my data` option (on ICS). Now I would like to check on my Google Account Preferences when was the last backup was made, and which data is safely backed up - and which isn't.

I'm not sure if that's possible. Does anybody know?

Comment: I believe one's best recourse would be to undertake a nandroid backup as well as use an app like Titanium Backup. Even if one isn't rooted, I believe that's a far more efficient and overall better way of backing up one's device.

Comment: I agree with sparkx. I had to restore my phone, so I restored it using a nandroid backup, but it wasn't working right, half my apps wouldn't open, half my settings were missing, and the apps that did open didn't work correctly. So I flashed the Stock ROM back on and restored my apps from a Titanium Backup that I did and that worked pretty well. (Although not perfectly, some of my apps still won't work right. Like Swype and TextPlus)

Comment: I should probably follow @Sparx advice, but well, having two backups is safer than one, besides, AFAIK, for a proper Titanium backup you need your phone rooted.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> I went to https://www.google.com/dashboard/b/0/ and found the section labeled "Android device"; that had a link labeled "More data stored about this device".  Clicking that opened a popup window that showed a disappointingly short list of apps that had backed up some of their data: just some of the built-in apps from Google.

The above paragraph was written in 2012; five years later the situation seems better: the relevant link is now https://myaccount.google.com/dashboard, and my list of apps is nice and long: 85, and they're not all from Google :-)

Comment: Mine doesn't even have anything under Android Devices :/

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, but I agree, the list is not complete at all.

Comment: @mdelolmo: The list shall be complete, but this is a feature that is be provided ('requested') by app's developers. Unfortunately few apps use (provide us) this feature integrated with google backup (look how it works: http://goo.gl/ABvsS)

Comment: Now Google seem to have moved the backup info to https://drive.google.com/drive/backups. However they only display the total number of apps that are backed up for each Android device. They no longer provide backup stats - date and size - for each app:(. Does anyone know where to find this now?

Comment: Five years later in 2021, looks like Google Dashboard is not showing non-Google apps/services anymore. While there's "Android Backups" entry showing the number of the apps, the last backup time is not there. And for unknown reasons, clicking the header goes to "Find My Device" (while "Delete backup data" goes to the right link, Google Drive's Backups).

Answer (score 1):

If you have Google Drive on your Android device then open it and go to *Backups*. Tap on the device's name you're interested in to see what's been backed up and when - App data, Call history, Device settings and SMS. Tap on *App data* to see the when each of your apps was last backed up.